# bash shell script that creates directories

Tags: shell-script, centos

Write a Bash shell script program which creates 3 directories `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3` and then places the following files into each directory `file1`, `file2`.  `file1` is a zero size and `file2` has the current date/time as the contents.  Create a file named `file3` that is only put into the `dir3` directory that contains the line from the `/etc/hosts` file that contains your hostname. Use a loop to create the directory and files. You will need to use an if condition block to create `file3` with the commands `grep` and `hostname`.

Comment: I been using this for reference but i'm obviously missing something        if [ $# -lt 3 ]
then
echo "Usage: $0 filename filename filename"
echo "Example: $0 Mary f1 f2 f3"
echo "Comments: Create a directory (e.g., Mary) and fill it with the named files (e.g., f1 f2 f3)"
exit 1
fi

#The next line makes the directory
mkdir $1

#The next line cds into that directory
cd $1

#The following line uses the "touch" command to make 3 files.
touch $2 $3 $4

for i in *
do
cp $i ..
done

Comment: You can [edit] your post with more information. You will get a better response if you show some level of effort.

Comment: nobody's going to put in the effort to read a comment like that.  Edit your question and add it there.  Use the `{}` icon to format it as code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for any looping. In fact, that would only be confusing an inefficient.

```
mkdir dir{1..3}
touch dir{1..3}/file1
date | tee dir{1..3}/file2 >/dev/null
grep "$(hostname)" /etc/hosts >dir3/file3
```

The only slightly advanced thing with this answer is the use of `tee`.  The `tee` utility will take data on standard input and duplicate this to a number of files, and again to standard output.  I use it here to write the date from the `date` utility into the three `file2` files. The redirection to `/dev/null` at the end is there so that we don't also get the date displayed in the terminal.

In the code above, `dir{1..3}` would be expanded to `dir1 dir2 dir3` and `dir{1..3}/file1` would be expanded to `dir1/file1 dir2/file1 dir3/file1` before the utility is invoked with that as its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This will do :

```
for i in {1..3}; do 
  mkdir dir$i
  touch dir$i/file1 
  date > dir$i/file2 
  if [ $i -eq 3 ]; then 
    grep $(hostname) /etc/hosts > dir$i/file3
  fi
done
```