# Issue with Bash Script creating Directories from Arrays

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

## Issue at hand

I am trying to write a bash script to quickly create a directory structure. This is an attempt to learn more about manipulating arrays, variables, and using loops. My script works to check for the existence of a directory then create folders. The issue I am having is creating a third level of directories within the first two layers.

## Goals

I want to be able to write a bash script that will create a directory structure of `~/a/a/a, ~/a/a/b, ~/a/a/c,...,~/a/z/z` for example. This should be flexible to so I could use any kind of array or variable that would be suitable.

## Here is what I have worked out so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
array_0=(one two three four five)
array_1=(x y z)

if [ ! -d "directory" ]; then
    mkdir directory
fi
for array_0 in "${array_0[@]}"
do
    mkdir ~/directory/$array_0/
done
if [ -d "~/directory/$array_0/" ]; then
   for array_1 in "${array_0[@]}"
   do
       mkdir ~/directory/$array_0/$array_1
   done
fi
exit 0
```

## Problem

The error I get is `mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/user/directory/one/x' : No such file or directory`

Other attempts at this script allow me to create `~/directory` and `~/directory/one, ~/directory/two,..., ~/directory/five` without fail but not the next level i.e `/directory/one/x` and etc.

How can I script the creation of this directory structure? Is this possible using arrays or is there another method?

For reference I tried to implement [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13334110) and elements from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277745/276845) but I have not had any luck creating the directory structure that I want.

Comment: `mkdir -p` will create all required directories.  For example you can do `mkdir -p one/two/three/four/five`  and it will create all the directories required (if they don't exist) in order to make `five`

Comment: `for array_0 in "${array_0[@]}"` Oops.

Comment: @ikkachu I posted the error, also that reference was a mistake. The script you see if the actual script this is simply an exercise in learning bash scripts.

Comment: @kemotep, the script has `x` in `array_1[0]`, but the first time `array_1` is referenced after the assignment is when `array_1` is used to loop over the values of `array_0`. So no, it doesn't look like that script would try to create `directory/one/x`, or otherwise lead to that error...

Comment: This question has multiple problems.  It is, of course, OK to post non-functioning scripts in questions, but it is not OK to post one version of a script along with an error message that comes from a different (unpublished) version of the script.

Comment: @Scott, This issue was resolved a while ago but I am quite confident that the above error is the one associated with the script. I understand and respect your concern, I just do not think that it applies. Could you point out where there are inconsistencies and the other issues you have?

Comment: OK, since you asked (some of these points are nit-picks): (1) Some sticklers say that there are no such thing as “folders” in Unix&Linux. Of course some file managers represent directories as folders, and I don’t have a big problem with using the terms interchangeably. But, when you say something like “check for the existence of a directory then create folders”, it makes us wonder whether you believe that they’re different things. (2) You talk about three levels of directories: `~/a/a/a` through `~/a/z/z`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If I mentioned `~/the/quick/brown/fox/jumps/over/the/lazy/dog/a/a` through `~/the/quick/brown/fox/jumps/over/the/lazy/dog/z/z`, would you call that an eleven-level directory structure?  No, of course not; it’s a two-level directory structure under a directory that’s nine levels down from `~`.  (3) The fact that you used three different names (in the original version of your question) for your top-level directory is confusing.  The fact that you called it `a` makes it look like you really are trying to create a three-level directory structure, `~/a/a/a` through `~/z/z/z`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  The fact that you called it `directory` is (trivially) confusing. (4) `for array_0 in "${array_0[@]}"` is an error.  If, for example, `qwerty` is an array, then `qwerty` by itself is an alias for `${querty[0]}`.  So your loop is setting `array_0[0]=${array_0[0]}` (i.e., setting it equal to itself), and then setting `array_0[0]=${array_0[1]}`, `array_0[0]=${array_0[2]}`, `array_0[0]=${array_0[3]}`, and finally `array_0[0]=${array_0[4]}`.  At the end of the loop, the array contains `(five two three four five)`, because `array_0[0]` was finally set to `${array_0[4]}`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) `for array_1 in "${array_0[@]}"` similarly changes the `array_1` array to `(five y z)`.  And, if using the name of an array as if it were an independent variable (which it isn’t) weren’t bad enough, this is using the name of one array as the name of an index variable into another array, which is terribly confusing.  (6) You should always quote all references to shell variables unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  Good job on getting `"${array_0[@]}"` right, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  but you should also quote the index variable when you use it in the `mkdir` command; for example, `mkdir ~/directory/"$a0"` (I’ve assumed that we have changed the index variable to `a0`, as in roaima’s answer; also, BTW, the `/` at the end is unnecessary, although harmless) or `mkdir "$HOME/web/$a0"` (again, à la roaima’s answer).  This is because array elements, just like any other variable, can contain spaces and other special characters.  If you had set ``array_0=("one two" "*" etc)``, then unquoted references to the index variable  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  would have resulted in field splitting and pathname expansion (which are bad things, in this context).  (7) Look closely at those last two examples (the `mkdir` commands).  Now look closely at the `if [ -d "~/directory/$array_0/" ]` test in your script.  Your script should never have passed that test, because, while variables get expanded inside double quotes (`"…"`), the `~` symbol does not.  So this test is looking for a directory called literally ``~/directory/five`` *and **not*** one called `/home/user/directory/five`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (You should either move the `~` outside the quotes, or use `$HOME` inside quotes.)  And there’s no reason for `~/directory/five` to exist, so this script should never have gotten to the second `mkdir`.  (8) Even if the script had, somehow, passed the `if` test and gotten into the `then` clause, it would have immediately set `array_1` (a.k.a. `array_1[0]`) to `array_0[0]` (which would be `five` at that point).  Your script never references the `array_1` array, *per se.*  And, as stated previously, `array_0` (a.k.a. `array_0[0]`) is also still set to ``five``.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  So, AFAICT, it’s impossible for your script to ever use the string `one/x` in any command. And yet you report an error message containing that string.

Comment: OK, I think that’s about it.  Obviously 4, 5, 7 and 8 are the major issues, and #6 is fairly important.  I hope you really wanted this.   (Be careful what you ask for.)

Comment: P.S.  I meant to acknowledge [ilkkachu’s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/426791/23408#comment769757_426791), which first pointed out that `array_1` (the variable) is used to loop over the values of (the array) `array_0`, and that the array ``array_1`` is never referenced.

Comment: @Scott, I really appreciate your feedback. My script did have horrible issues but it is why I asked the question to get answers on how to do what I wanted and to learn how to better make it work. With user roaima's feedback I was able to solve the issue. I can confidently say that I understand bash better now. The post was edited which is why there may be some inconsistencies. Thanks for all the feedback I definitely understand why you would raise those points. If you feel that the question could be better edited to remove the issues and improve the quality of the question, please do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested array loop, like this

```
#!/bin/bash
array_0=(one two three four five)
array_1=(x y z)

for a0 in "${array_0[@]}"
do
   for a1 in "${array_1[@]}"
   do
       mkdir -p "$HOME/web/$a0/$a1"
   done
done
```

Or, if you don't mind avoiding the use of arrays but using expansion lists instead, this single command will do much the same thing:

```
mkdir -p ~/{one,two,three,four,five}/{x,y,z}
```

Comment: I did not know you could do this in a one-liner. I just learned of arrays and thought that they would help. Your `mkdir -p ~/{one,two,three,four,five}/{x,y,z}` example works great. Thank you, I was making this too complicated.

Comment: @kemotep there's definitely a time and place for arrays so don't worry about this not necessarily being one of them.